How far from the breaker can I place an irrigation pump on #12 wire?
I have a 230 volt, single phase irrigation pump on a 12-2 AWG, 20 amp breaker that I want to move. How far can I place this load from the source (breaker)? The wire will be suitable for direct burial but will be placed in a 3.4" electrical conduit.

What is the amps/watts the pump uses?  How far is it now?

Did you mean 3/4" conduit?

You can't put Romex outdoors.  (NM cable) including in conduit.  Water destroys it.  It's cheap.    If the conduit is complete the entire route, use THHN.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica OP said "direct burial" which means UF. But of course should use wires as cheaper/easier if you're using conduit anyway.

As far as you want :-)
But seriously, the only issue should be voltage drop. And that depends on the voltage (note: 230V is actually a bit odd - that's an old standard in the US, currently most places have 240V, but calculations below are for 230V anyway and with 240V you actually get a slightly lower voltage drop), length of the wire and the resistance of the wire and the amount of current. The resistance depends on the thickness of the wire. 12 AWG is generally the minimum for a 20A circuit. Certainly up to 100 feet you will be fine. Beyond that it also depends on the allowable voltage drop. The gold standard is 3%, but often 5% or even more is acceptable. Sticking with 3% and rounding up to the nearest foot:

20A load - the maximum on a 20A circuit

12 AWG - 100 feet
10 AWG - 165 feet
8 AWG - 250 feet


16A load - the maximum continuous on a 20A circuit

12 AWG - 125 feet
10 AWG - 206 feet
8 AWG - 313 feet


10A load - 1/2 the capacity of a 20A circuit

12 AWG - 199 feet
10 AWG - 329 feet
8 AWG - 500 feet



Note that you can mix sizes. For example, you could have 20 feet of 12 AWG wire from the panel to a junction box on the wall and then run 10 AWG wire in conduit to the pump and the actual drop will be determined by the drop for each wire size x length added together.
There is no reason to use direct bury cable inside conduit. Use individual wet-rated (THWN) wires in conduit - it will be much easier than pulling cable.
